# Xamarin iOS - Implementation of Interactive Pop Gesture Recognizer

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, user-experience

I am trying to implement a Interactive Pop Gesture Recognizer so I could swipe left to right and go back one page (Like Settings on iOS). My goal is to add this functionality in one place and it would affect the whole app.
I have tried adding recognizer on the base View Controller with `ViewDidLoad` and `ViewWillAppear` methods but it doesn't work. I also have tried adding it on App Delegate file but it doesn't work. How exactly I should implement this?

My Code for implementation looks as follows (in View Controller) but it doesn't work:
`ViewWillAppear(bool animated){
...
 NavigationController.InteractivePopGestureRecognizer.Delegate = this;
 NavigationController.InteractivePopGestureRecognizer.Enabled= true;
...
}`

 It seems that `NavigationController`is null in my `ViewController` on `ViewWillAppear` method

Comment: Hey there, I see this is super old, but did you ever figure it out? Facing the same exact issue myself. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your NavigationController is null in ViewWillAppear that means you aren't currently using a NavigationController which is where this swipe back behavior comes from.

If you instead use a UINavigationController wherever you are pushing/presenting/setting your current UIViewController then it should work.

Something like:

```
Window.RootViewController = new UINavigationController(yourViewController);
```

instead of:

```
Window.RootViewController = yourViewController;
```